# Differences between several ways to declare an empty/default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, standards, c++14, default-constructor

In C++14 there are several ways to declare an empty constructor

```
class C1 {
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};

class C2 {
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int val = 0;
};

class C3 {
    constexpr C3() noexcept = default;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};

class C4 {
    constexpr C4() noexcept = default;
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int val = 0;
};

class C5 {
    constexpr C5() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} = default;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};

class C6 {
    constexpr C6() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} {}
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};

class C7 {
    constexpr C7() noexcept;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
constexpr C7::C7() noexcept = default;

class C8 {
    constexpr C8() noexcept;
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int val = 0;
};
constexpr C8::C8() noexcept = default;

class C9 {
    constexpr C9() noexcept;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
constexpr C9::C9() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} = default;

class C10 {
    constexpr C10() noexcept;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
constexpr C10::C10() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} {}
```

I am wondering, what are the exact differences between all these classes and what classes are strictly equivalent, and will produce the exact same behaviour according to the C++ standard.

Comment: C3, C5, C7 and C9 are illegal.

Comment: Did all of those compile for you? If so, which compiler and with what options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class C1 {
    int* ptr;
    int val;
}
```

The compile will declare and define a public trivial `noexcept` default ctor. Being trivial, it won't perform **any** initialization of the members.
A user can choose between default-initialization (which won't perform any init of the data members) or value-initialization (which will zero-initialize the data members):

```
C1 x;        // default-initialized
C1 y = C1(); // value-initialized
```

A trivial default ctor has an influence on object lifetime and the PODness of the class.

If `C1` were a `struct` (that is, the data members being public), it would be an aggregate:

```
C1 a {nullptr, 42};
C1 z{};      // aggregate-initialized, but same effects as for y
```

Despite the default ctor not being `constexpr`, you can create instances of this class within constant expressions: Being trivial, the default ctor won't be called in value-initialization (nor in aggregate-initialization).

---

```
class C2 {
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int val = 0;
};
```

The compiler will declare and define a public `constexpr` and `noexcept` default ctor, which initializes the data members according to their NSDMIs (non-static data member initializers, i.e. the `= x;`). Both default- and value-initialization will call the default ctor and initialize the members. A `struct C2` would be an aggregate according to C++14 rules.

---

```
class C3 {
    constexpr C3() noexcept = default;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
```

Is illegal, because constructor the compiler would declare itself (see `C1`) wouldn't be `constexpr`. It is not `constexpr` because it doesn't initialize all data members. Note that all of the user-declared ctors in the OP are (implicitly) private.

---

```
class C4 {
    constexpr C4() noexcept = default;
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int val = 0;
};
```

Same as `C2`.

---

```
class C5 {
    constexpr C5() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} = default;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
```

Gramatically illegal. You cannot default only the function body, you have to default the whole constructor.

---

```
class C6 {
    constexpr C6() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} {}
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
```

Same effects as `C2`, except this is a private ctor and `struct C6` would no longer be an aggregate because this ctor is user-provided.

---

```
class C7 {
    constexpr C7() noexcept;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
constexpr C7::C7() noexcept = default;
```

Illegal for the same reason as `C3`.

---

```
class C8 {
    constexpr C8() noexcept;
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    int val = 0;
};
constexpr C8::C8() noexcept = default;
```

Since the ctor is not defaulted at its first declaration, this is a (private) *user-provided* default ctor. Therefore, same behaviour as `C6`.

---

```
class C9 {
    constexpr C9() noexcept;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
constexpr C9::C9() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} = default;
```

Illegal for the same reason as `C3`.

---

```
class C10 {
    constexpr C10() noexcept;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
constexpr C10::C10() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} {}
```

Same as `C8`; `constexpr` functions are implicitly inline.

Comment: C2 is not an aggregate either, since it has private non-static data members due to being declared a `class` and not a `struct`. Besides that, all given classes are virtually unusable, so let's imagine they were `struct`s ;) Very nice and thorough answer yet!

Comment: @dasdave d'oh! I didn't pay any attention at all to the `class` key.

Comment: How does the triviality of a constructor have an effect on object lifetime?

Comment: @0x499602D2 See [basic.life]p1. For an object with a trivial default ctor, object lifetime begins with allocation.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the code above code is illegal and will not compile. I'll go through the errors and explain why they are errors.

```
class C3 {
    constexpr C3() noexcept = default;
    // A constexpr constructor cannot be defaulted since the default
    // version of the constructor is not constexpr. In this case, you will
    // thus have to always explicitly define a constexpr constructor.
// ...
};

// For C4, on the other hand, defaulting the constexpr will work since
// you gave default (constant) values for all members. The default
// constructor will not have to care about them.

class C5 {
    constexpr C5() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} = default;
    // Besides this being invalid syntax, you are implicitly defining
    // a constructor, and then using the default version of it, which
    // does not make sense.
// ...
};

// The rest of the errors are just plain reproduction in a slightly
// amended form.
```

Besides that, the (valid) code will produce the exact same *runtime*-behavior; The constructors declared `constexpr` will, if used in a `constexpr`-context, be evaluated at compile time (which is a good thing usually since it saves some computation). An example would be:

```
constexpr auto some_c10 = C10{};
// or
constexpr void do_something() { // works for constexpr functions as well! yay!
    auto some_other_c10 = c10{};
}
```

It is worth noting that a non-`constexpr`-version of `some_c10` will call the exact same `constexpr` version of the constructor at runtime, unless a non-`costexpr` version is specified, whereas this version will evaluate the `constexpr` constructor at compile time. The `constexpr`-context here is created by using the `constexpr` keyword obviously; omitting it will result in the non-`constexpr`-version unless a smart compiler chooses to declare it `constexpr` anyway.

In addition, the first class will implicitly create a trivial constructor, that is, the constructor will not perform any actions and keep the values uninitialized (nevermind here: it would create a trivial constructor, but since the given types are classes, they have non-static private members, which prevents a compiler from defining such a constructor. Declaring C1 a `struct` would have worked though).

Other than that, there is really no difference in the various spellings you found. It is mainly just another way of expressing the exact same thing. Although the out-of-line definition of functions should be the preferred solution in almost all cases.

Answer (score 0):

These All produce same behavior but with little difference at  **compile time**. 
The firstand Second  one are  so simple so.. starting from third one
When you are using Constructor as

```
class C3 {
    constexpr C3() noexcept = default;
    int* ptr;
    int val;
}
```

by using constexpr value doesn't change in any case we can also use cont and by using noexcept we are checking whether it returns true or not at compile time SAME GOES FOR ALL the other(just for understanding)

```
class C6 {
    constexpr C6() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, val{0} {}
    int* ptr;
    int val;
};
```

If we talk about it then we are doing member initialization this is quite fast as compiler time is saved by  little milliseconds it's huge for big programs. 
That's a little diffrence i could tell Hope it will be useful even little.